# R Create print table with different types of data in it

Tags: r, kable, flextable

Here is my problem

I have this sample data.frame :

```
Name=c("a","b","c","d")
Value=c(12.3,10.5,2.6,1.2)
Label=c("label1","label2","label3","label4")
df=data.frame(Name,Value,Label)
```

I want to create a table only for displaying (in a Rnotebook) with the data in df but flipping rows and columns.

[wanted displayed table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbLdW.png)

Is it an efficient way to do it ? flextable or kable do not seem to have flipping possibilities.

A data.frame transposition is not a solution since columns can't mix different data types (numeric, character)...

I can't imagine nobody encountered the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a custom function to "flip" your dataframe you could do:

```
flip_df <- function(x) {
  x <- data.frame(t(x))
  x <- cbind(row.names(x), x)
  names(x) <- x[1,]
  x[-1, ]  
}

library(flextable)

flextable(flip_df(df))
```

[image]

Comment: That's so simple.... Works perfectly...